# Wifi signal very slow, works only for REALLY small distance | Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, wireless-router, wifi-configuration

I am on ubuntu 16.04 and my wifi won't work if I am a little far from my router

My card is Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 (Lenovo G5070)

and here are my device settings:

```
wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"ooredooE9BDC0"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: A4:B1:E9:E9:BD:C0   
          Bit Rate=6.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=26/70  Signal level=-84 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:93   Missed beacon:0
```

output of `lspci -nn | grep -i net`

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
```

Help please

Comment: Is this a new problem, eg after an update. Does it behave the same on a different OS (Ubuntu LiveCD, Windows diagnostic disc, etc)? Have you tried different channels on your router?

Comment: Yes it is a new problem, I only have Ubuntu on my computer but other computers work perfectly fine with the same router

Comment: Yes, but is it new on that machine, or have you only just started using it?

Comment: I have been using this machine for a long time but this issue just appeared lately

Comment: If you had not done a software update prior to seeing the problem, then it is more likely to be a hardware issue, but boot a LiveCD to check if the problem persists. If not, then check the settings and driver revisions on this system.

Comment: If range has suddenly decreased then it it quite likely that the antenna has become disconnected from your Wifi card.  You'll need to open up the machine, find the wifi card and check for a cable that looks like it should be connected, but isn't, or a cable that is only marginally connected.

Answer (score 0):

I am using lenovo Y50-70 which has the same problem with adapter QCA9565

Try this as root

```
$modprobe -r ath9k

$modprobe ath9k nohwcrypt=1
```